# syntax error, unexpected '$Name' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

syntax error, unexpected **'$Name'** (T_VARIABLE) error appears for this line

My query is-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email) VALUES ("$Name","$Email")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quote in value

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email) VALUES ("$Name","$Email")";
```

**To**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use quote chars like that, the second one would terminate the string you define. Instead try using different types of quotes. That allows to actually have a quote character inside your defined string.

Take a look at this modified and working version:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name, Email) VALUES ('$Name', '$Email')";
```

Be aware however that such creation of a sql statement smells very much of sql injection attack vulnerability...